# truck vibrates even in park

Tags: transmission

my ram blew the engine (17000miles)when they towed it they dragged it 8 Ft in park. Now I have a new engine and a very noticeable  vibration . Could it be from the transmission?? Dodge is saying the engine needs to come back out.its the 6 cyl diesel engine. Thanks.   its a 2015 model

Comment: We to the site! If you could add the model year of your vehicle that would help us help you.

Comment: Didn't ask about a dealership . I asked if the incident could cause a vibration in the transmission .truck has 100k warranty

Comment: .Also what does the model year have to do with my question or your response

Comment: the vibration is occurring when the trans is in park. This means the majority of the trans is rotating. Not very likely that the trans is the problem. "Could it be?" Sure. But so could a meteor. Most likely the vibration is coming from the motor. Model year gives unique information about configuration.

Answer (score 2):

So, it should still be under warranty right? If yes, give back to Dodge and just let them do whatever they need. It shouldn't be a transmission related problem. Keep careful documentation of everything they do so if there are still problems they have to fix it.

If the towing really did damage something bad, then it's their insurances problem to handle.